# C# Expression Tree Adding to List<> Prop

Tags: c#, expression, expression-trees

I have a below-mentioned person class and I've "IEnumerable of MemberInitExpression" which is having values for contacts in the form of MemberInitExpression.

```
public class Person
{
    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

Using expression tree how can I populate Contacts prop from IEnumerable.

I've tried below logic but it gives an exception.

```
var method = typeof(List<Person>).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "Add").First().MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Person));
```

Exception:
*Void Add(Microsoft.PS.OrderToCash.TM.BusinessRuleEngine.RuleResultTree) is not a GenericMethodDefinition. MakeGenericMethod may only be called on a method for which MethodBase.IsGenericMethodDefinition is true.'*

Single MemberInitExpression from the collection I am able to bind as below

```
Expression.Bind(childResultProp, childRuleResults.FirstOrDefault());
```

Please suggest how can I populate MemberInitExpression in Contact prop collection.

Comment: You have to work more on your question. The way it is now, it's really unclear what are you asking. The exception is obviously from the `MakeGenericMethod` call (`List<T>.Add` method is **not generic** method as exception message clearly indicates), so just remove it. For other issues, update the question. And provide [mcve]. If you are wondering what it is, try creating a new console project and compose something from the currently posted snippets and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: A `MemberInitExpression` will allow you to _assign_ `Contacts`, but to actually _populate_ it, you'll need a `ListInitExpression` containing a sequence of `ElementInit` values.

Comment: You are the man Mike, please post it as an answer so that I can accept it :)